# How can I import contacts into iPhone from Palm Centro?

Tags: iphone, contacts, import

I'm planning on purchasing an iPhone 4, and I want to know the most direct method of copying my contacts from my Palm Centro to my iPhone. Extra points for solutions that work on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look into [SyncML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SyncML), it was the only way i managed to get my contacts out of my decade old Nokia.

I'm not sure what the iPhone uses as a contact manager on Linux (Would [MobileMe](http://www.me.com) be a good workaround?), but once you've got them out, it's a lot easier to import them into something else.

[Google Sync](http://www.google.com/mobile/sync/) is also worth a look and would avoid your desktop altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I used the palm conduit to send everything that was in palm desktop (windows - not Linux) to Outlook. Then I synced the iPhone with Outlook. Notes disappeared but most of the other data fields were OK

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Funambol](http://www.funambol.com/solutions/portal.php). I've used it to sync my contacts from my old Sony Ericsson into my iPhone... Never tried with a Palm Centro though, but it'll probably work.

You need first to install the app in your old phone, sync with the server, install the app in the iPhone and sync back.

It's also a great way to backup your contacts.